# Swift game same message

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, swift2

I get the same message every time when (count) is bigger then (highscored).

But what i want is when (count) is lower then (highscored) you get 
("You scored (count) points").

I am an student and did an tutorial about swift, so now i am adding some things to learn, its an tap game, you need to tap as fast as possible to set a new highscore.

This is the section what i am talking about :

```
func subtractTime() {
    seconds--
    timerLabel.text = "Time: \(seconds)"

    if(seconds == 0)  {
        if(highscored < count)
        {
            highscored < count
            saveHighScore(count)
            highscore.text = "Highscore: \(loadhighScore().description)"
        }

        if (highscored > count) {
            timer.invalidate()
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Time is up!",
                message: "You scored \(count) points",
                preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            alert.addAction (UIAlertAction(title: "Play Again", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {
                action in self.setupGame()
            }))
            presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion:nil)
        }
        else{
        timer.invalidate()
        let alert2 = UIAlertController(title: "Time is up!",
            message: "You set a new higscore \(count) points",
            preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            alert2.addAction (UIAlertAction(title: "Play Again", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {
            action in self.setupGame()
        }))
            presentViewController(alert2, animated: true, completion:nil)}



    }}
```

This is the hole code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var scoreLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var timerLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var highscore: UILabel!


var count = 0
var seconds = 0
var timer = NSTimer()
var highscored = 0


@IBAction func buttonPressed()  {
    count++
    scoreLabel.text = "Score \n\(count)"
}


func setupGame() { if(highscored > count) {
    seconds = 30
    count = 0
    timerLabel.text = "Time: \(seconds)"
    scoreLabel.text = "Score:\(count)"
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: Selector("subtractTime"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
else  {
    seconds = 30
    count = 0
    timerLabel.text = "Time: \(seconds)"
    scoreLabel.text = "Score:\(count)"
    highscore.text = "Highscore: \(loadhighScore().description)"
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: Selector("subtractTime"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
}


func subtractTime() {
    seconds--
    timerLabel.text = "Time: \(seconds)"

    if(seconds == 0)  {
        if(highscored < count)
        {
            highscored < count
            saveHighScore(count)
            highscore.text = "Highscore: \(loadhighScore().description)"
        }

        if (highscored > count) {
            timer.invalidate()
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Time is up!",
                message: "You scored \(count) points",
                preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            alert.addAction (UIAlertAction(title: "Play Again", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {
                action in self.setupGame()
            }))
            presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion:nil)
        }
        else{
        timer.invalidate()
        let alert2 = UIAlertController(title: "Time is up!",
            message: "You set a new higscore \(count) points",
            preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            alert2.addAction (UIAlertAction(title: "Play Again", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {
            action in self.setupGame()
        }))
            presentViewController(alert2, animated: true, completion:nil)}



    }}


func saveHighScore(high:Int) {
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(high, forKey: "highscore")
}
func loadhighScore() -> Int {
    return NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("highscore")
}
func resetHighScore() {
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().removeObjectForKey("highscore")
}




override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
setupGame()



}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never actually assign a value to `highscored` and so it is always set to the `0` value you originally declare it as.

Because of this, the expression `if (highscored > count)` will never return true, and so you will never execute the code you are after. Your possible scenarios are that count is greater than zero (If the user taps the button at all), which will trigger the `if(highscored < count)` if statement, or that count is equal to highscored (If the user doesn't tap the button at all), at which point the program will fail the `highscored > count` expression, and move onto the else statement, at which point it tells the user they have a new high score.

A good solution to this would be to set the value of highScored to the current high score in the `setupGame()` method, like so:

```
func setupGame() { 
    highscored = loadhighscore()
    seconds = 30
    count = 0
    timerLabel.text = "Time: \(seconds)"
    scoreLabel.text = "Score:\(count)"
    if(highscored > count) {
        highscore.text = "Highscore: \(loadhighScore().description)"
    }
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: Selector("subtractTime"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```

Another thing worth mentioning, although this isn't causing any bugs with your code, is that you have what seems to be a redundant if statement in your `subtractTime()` method, as you first check if highscored is greater than count, and then you also check if it's greater than or equal to count in the following `else` part of the next if statement. If this is intentional then ignore this next big of code, however I'd probably format it something like;

```
func subtractTime() {
    seconds--
    timerLabel.text = "Time: \(seconds)"

    if(seconds == 0)  {
        timer.invalidate()

        if(highscored <= count)
        {
            saveHighScore(count)
            highscore.text = "Highscore: \(loadhighScore().description)"

            let alert2 = UIAlertController(title: "Time is up!",
                message: "You set a new higscore \(count) points",
                preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            alert2.addAction (UIAlertAction(title: "Play Again", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {
                action in self.setupGame()
            }))
                presentViewController(alert2, animated: true, completion:nil)
        }
        else {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Time is up!",
                message: "You scored \(count) points",
                preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            alert.addAction (UIAlertAction(title: "Play Again", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {
                action in self.setupGame()
            }))
            presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion:nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Hopefully this helps